# I'm puzzled by a specific link

Tags: support

user2987538 has asked a question {since deleted} on Web Apps and the profile shows membership of Database Administrators, where user has asked two questions, one of which:

[image: Craig Ephraim]

when clicked goes to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29043/postgresql-duplicate-key-violates-unique-constraint-error posted by Craig Efrein who seems unrelated. Can anybody explain what this signifies please?

I am not signed up for Database Administrators nor Meta StackExchange hence asking here.

Comment: Link to the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The user's question on DBA is marked as duplicate of Craig's question and anonymous users are redirected to Craig's question. Hence you see question linked to Craig.

Comment: Don't worry, i was puzzled for a bit too till i realized what was happening!